# How to redirect and open new tab in one click

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

In page one : Form and submit to page two

page two : Insert data, open new tab and redirect to page one

I'm using

```
window.open("pdf_order.php?p=<?=$paper;?>","_blank");
window.location = "page1.php";
```

but, It's doesn't work because block popup on browser.

Comment: So you want to open a popup when they arrive on page2. Sorry, not gonna happen. :-) You'll want to change this clickflow.

Comment: why open new tab in page2 if you will be redirected to the page1 ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you want to issue a `window.open` call when you arrive on "page two."

You can't, because that's what scuzzy websites used to do, and this is the whole point of popup blockers. Instead, you'll need to adjust the clickflow so you're not trying to do that.

Answer (score -1):

This is a question of the type: **Doing X is not allowed. How to do X?**

> If a popup blocker allowed you to do a popup, it would be a very bad
>   blocker, and people would not use it.

Please understand that a popup blocker is always a step ahead of you: it uses interface to a concrete Web browser which in turn take a total control of all rendering and scripting on the client side. And your application is supposed to work with all kinds of HTTP client software and be somewhat abstracted from it. From this point, it's easy to understand that it's much easier for a blocker to block your code then break this blocking.

found this answer on http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/474314/PopUpplusBlockerplusisplusdisplayingpluswhenplusop

try AJAX

Comment: Please specify reason while down-voting :)